# WPF - Why does the Visual studio design surface stop databinding when using a button ControlTemplate defined in a different assembly?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, wpf-controls

I've been working on the current project for just over a year, and I'm now trying to retro fit design time data into the views. The application has a base resource dictionary that contains the default styles for controls. The application is able to load a plugin that can override some or all of the default styles, hence why the resource dictionary is contained in an external assembly in the following example.

NOTE: This isn't such a big problem with the supplied demo project, but is causing headaches in the actual application that highlighted the problem in the first place.

#### The view:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DesignTimeData.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DesignTimeData"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:ViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True, CreateList=False}"
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/ViewsModule;component/Styles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                   Style="{DynamicResource TextStyle}"
                   Text="{Binding Row1Text}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                   Style="{DynamicResource TextStyle}"
                   Text="{Binding Row2Text}" />
        <Button Content="Button Text"
                Grid.Row="2"
                Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

#### The ViewModel:

```
namespace DesignTimeData
{
    class ViewModel
    {
        private string row1Text;

        public string Row1Text
        {
            get { return row1Text; }
            set { row1Text = value; }
        }

        private string row2Text;

        public string Row2Text
        {
            get { return row2Text; }
            set { row2Text = value; }
        }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            row1Text = "Dummy Row 1";
            row2Text = "Dummy Row 2";
        }
    }
}
```

#### The ResourceDictionary(contained in an external assembly):

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style x:Key="TextStyle"
           TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="CornflowerBlue" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize"
                Value="28" />
        <Setter Property="TextAlignment"
                Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="Beige" />
    </Style>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="CustomButtonTemplate"
                     TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0"
                                                             EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                            <GradientStop Offset="0"
                                                          Color="LightBlue" />
                                            <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                                          Color="DarkBlue" />
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <ContentPresenter  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle"
           TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0"
                                     EndPoint="0.5,1">
                    <GradientStop Offset="0"
                                  Color="DarkBlue" />
                    <!--<GradientStop Offset="0.5"
                                  Color="Blue" />-->
                    <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                  Color="LightBlue" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                Value="Red" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                Value="3" />
        <Setter Property="Content"
                Value="{Binding Content}" />
        <Setter Property="Padding"
                Value="5,5,5,5" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize"
                Value="26" />
        <Setter Property="Width"
                Value="200" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="DarkBlue" />
        <Setter Property="Template"
                Value="{StaticResource CustomButtonTemplate}" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

If I copy the contents of the resource dictionary directly into the `UserControl.Resources` property then this seems to work as expected, each TextBlock has the databound text displayed and the button has the expected size and content. If I attempt to import the external dictionary using `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionary` as follows:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/ViewsModule;component/Styles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

then the designer doesn't update correctly. The TextBlocks have no content and the grid shrinks to the size of the (hardcoded) button content.
The designer appears to be honouring the styles defined in the resource dictionary but the presence of the `ControlTemplate` appears to be breaking the data binding. If the `ControlTemplate` and associated `Setter` in the `ButtonStyle` style block are removed then the designer behaves normally. Also, changing the `Padding` property in the `ButtonStyle` also causes the designer to refresh the data binding and all appears normal, until the application is compiled at which point the data binding breaks and its back to the minimalist design surface again.

I don't know if this will be an issue in Expression Blend. Unfortunately I don't currently have access to Blend as the trial version I had previously installed has expired.

Does anybody have an idea as to what is going on here and more importantly, how to fix it?

A VS2012 demo solution can be found [here](http://www.ydiren.com/SOFiles/DesignTimeData.zip).